# Redux Connect with Typescript - TS2347

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm new to Typescript and though it is fascinating and a life-saver, this error is quite a hard nut to crack.

**TypeScript error: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.  TS2347**

Can you please tell me what should be improved in the below class to get rid of this error ?

Here is the whole class

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react'
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'



type StateProps = {
  mbzArtists: IMBZArtist[],
  releaseArtistID: string
}

type DispatchProps = {
  findMBZReleases: (artistID: string) => void,
}

type OwnProps = {}

type MBZSearchResultsProps = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps

const MBZSearchResults: FunctionComponent<MBZSearchResultsProps> = ({ findMBZReleases, mbzArtists, releaseArtistID }) => {
  return (
    <div className="MBZSearchResults">
      // div content
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
  return {
    mbzArtists: state.musicBrainz.mbzArtists,
    releaseArtistID: state.musicBrainz.artistReleaseID
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any): DispatchProps => {
  return {
    findMBZReleases: (artistID: string) => dispatch(Actions.MBZActions.findMBZReleases(artistID))
  }
}

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MBZSearchResults)
```

In case you require more information, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed by changing the export statement as below:
const component: React.FunctionComponent<OwnProps> = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MBZSearchResults)

export default component

Can I please have a comment from typescript users to let me know if this is the way to go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed by changing the export statement as below:

```js
const component: React.FunctionComponent<OwnProps> = 
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MBZSearchResults)

export default component
```

Can I please have a comment from typescript users to let me know if this is the way to go ?

Comment: I understand it as being a way of separating public vs internal props that will be used by your component.  Public props are those props that will be changed/passed down by other components/user-intervention.  Internal/Private props are those kind of props that are inherited in a way; for example 'navigation' prop if you use react-navigation.   Hence, you don't want your users to be able to mess with those internal props.

Answer (score 0):

As stated from the error you posted.

> TypeScript error: Untyped function calls may not accept type
>   arguments. TS2347

The connect function dosen't accept type arguments.

Change the export connect to this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MBZSearchResults)
```

Comment: If we do it like this, then there won't be any props validation on this component and one can put in any number of props when calling it.  I already tried this out and the types and way of writing this component have been researched before coming to SO.
Did you try this out on your side?